# Which is better between defining a variable near its context or avoid repeated allocation/initialisation?

Tags: loops, for-loop, code-cleanup

My examples from Python, but I guess the concept applies to most languages. Suppose I have the following scenario

```
for element in big_list:
    temp_var=something # This remains constant throughout the iterations
    # Looping clause
```

Here, `temp_var` is a constant variable that is necessary within the loop. But if it remains constant, should I define it just before starting the `for` loop? The two conflicting principles here are

1. Variables should be defined with the smallest scope possible so as to not crowd the namespace. It is an argument for doing as above, which also keeps the variable closer to the context of usage.
2. But defining inside the loop requires repeated initialisation and allocation on each iteration. Or is it something the compiler/interpreter optimises so that I can turn a blind eye anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

As the variable will not change inside the loop, I definitely choose to define it before the loop. Also, reason 1 is unuseful if variable it isn't unallocated before exiting the loop, I mean, it will remain alive after the loop. After exit the loop, you can unset the variable. So, my approach will be:

```
temp_var = something # This remains constant throughout the iterations
for element in big_list:
    # Looping clause
# loop ended
del temp_var # If it's not needed anymore
```

I'm sorry I don't manage python, but I think this "code" is easily understood, and applicable to almost any language.